# Can not get post from others in Facebook Group API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API to get all post from my group which I am admin. But I can only get posts which posted by myself.

Here is my url to call api:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{my-group-id}/feed?access_token={my-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7Bmy-group-id%7D/feed?access_token=%7Bmy-token%7D)

How I can get post by the other member?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you go through app review yet, and got your use of the Groups API feature approved? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/groups-api

Comment: @CBroe my app is in development mode so groups api feature approved or not? i can't display posts by other admins in my groups by the token of the app which in development mode.